# rotational symmetries of the 120-cell

Tags: rotations, symmetry, polytopes

I want to find the number of rotational symmetries of the 120-cell but I am not very familiar with polytopes nor counting symmetries. So, I don't know if someone can give me an idea or an example with some other polytope or a reference to read about it. Any help is welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Coxeter's "Regular Polytopes" (p. 130) the order of the reflectional symmetry group of an $n$ dimensional regular polytope 
$\{p,q,...,v,w\}$ is given by

$$g_{\ p,q,...,v,w}=N_{n-1}N_{n-1,n-2}\cdots N_{2,1}N_{1,0}$$

simply by counting the according fundamental regions of the mirror hyperplane dissections.

Now consider the according incidence matrix of the 120-cell $\{5,3,3\}$.

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
600 & 4 & 6 & 4\\
2 & 1200 & 3 & 3\\
5 & 5 & 720 & 2\\
20 & 30 & 12 & 120
\end{array}$$

we get accordingly

$$g_{\ 5,3,3}=120\cdot 12\cdot 5\cdot 2=14400$$

As 2 consecutive reflections make up a rotation (even within 4D) 
you would have simply divide the above value by 2 to get the order of the rotational subgroup, i.e. 7200.

--- rk